# Android: Deleting items from a sorted RealmRecyclerViewAdapter removes wrong item?

Tags: java, android, realm

I just tried to sort my items in a `RecyclerView` by the timestamp they were created. First it seemed to work fine, but there is a strange **bug** which sometimes occures when **deleting** items from the `RecyclerView`.

My RealmAdapter looks as follows:

```
public class RealmMedicineListAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Medicine, RealmMedicineListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.item_bullet_list_medicine_tv_title)
        TextView tvMedicineTitle;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
        }

        void bindData(@NonNull Medicine medicine) {
            tvMedicineTitle.setText(medicine.getTitle());
        }
    }

    public RealmMedicineListAdapter(@Nullable OrderedRealmCollection<Medicine> data, boolean autoUpdate) {
        super(data, autoUpdate);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_bullet_list_medicine, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(row);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Medicine medicine = getItem(position);

        if(medicine == null)
            throw new IllegalStateException("'medicine may not be null'");

        holder.bindData(medicine);
    }
}
```

Binding the data to the `adapter`:

```
RealmList<Medicine> consumedMedicine;
// ... 

medicineListAdapter.updateData(consumedMedicine.sort("timeStamp"));
```

The timestamp is generated whenever a new `Medicine` item is created:

```
public Medicine() {
        timeStamp = new Date().getTime();
}
```

The sorting works fine even when new items are added to the `consumedMedicine` list, but it gets weird when deleting items from that list. Sometimes, not always, when I delete an item from the list the wrong item is being removed.

**This picture should express what I mean:** 
https://ibb.co/hTmUoF

The code for deleting an item is stated below:

```
// Callback when the user deletes a row item in the RecyclerView
realm.executeTransaction(realm -> medicineEntry.deleteMedicine(realm, position));
// ...

public void deleteMedicine(int position) {
        if(position < 0 || position >= consumedMedicine.size()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'position' must be in range of [0, "
                    + consumedMedicine.size() + "[ --- passed 'position': " + position);
        }

        Medicine itemToDelete = consumedMedicine.get(position);
        if(!isUndoPointSet) {
         //Not important for now!
            LoggingUtils.databaseAction("DELETED medicine item with TITLE " + itemToDelete.getTitle() + " from DB.");
            itemToDelete.deleteFromRealm();
        } else { 
         //NOTE: This might be the code that causes this unwanted behaviour.
                itemToDelete.setPendingDelete(true);
                pendingList.add(itemToDelete);
                consumedMedicine.remove(itemToDelete);
                LoggingUtils.databaseAction("Medicine item TITLE " + itemToDelete.getTitle() + " is now PENDING_DELETE.");
            }
```

**Note:** The `pendingList` is a `RealmList<Medicine>` that contains all items that have been newly added or removed by the user (this items are marked by 'pending'-flags), so that these actions can be undone later. E.g. if the user decides to save his actions all items with flag 'pendingDelete' will be deleted from the database, etc.
In my case, the unwanted behaviour of the `RecyclerView` happens only when `isUndoPointSet` is true.

Is that because the order in the `RealmRecyclerViewAdapter` isn´t the same as the sorted `consumedMedicine` list? But the auto-updating feature should keep care of that, or am I wrong? Thanks.

**EDIT:** I think I´ve fixed it now, I have testet it a few times and it really seems to work now.

```
public void deleteMedicine(@NonNull Realm realm, int position) {
        if(position < 0 || position >= consumedMedicine.size()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("'position' must be in range of [0, "
                    + consumedMedicine.size() + "[ --- passed 'position': " + position);
        }

        //This caused the problems!
        //Medicine itemToDelete = consumedMedicine.get(position);

        //The below line is the important change!
        Medicine itemToDelete = getMedicineSortedByTime().get(position);
        if(!isUndoPointSet) {
            LoggingUtils.databaseAction("DELETED medicine item at with TITLE " + itemToDelete.getTitle() + " at pos " + position + " from DB.");
            itemToDelete.deleteFromRealm();
        } else {
            itemToDelete.setPendingDelete(true);
            pendingList.add(itemToDelete);
            consumedMedicine.remove(itemToDelete);
            LoggingUtils.databaseAction("Medicine item TITLE " + itemToDelete.getTitle() + " on pos " + position + " is now PENDING_DELETE.");
        }
    }
```

I think the problem was the following: The adapter represents the **sorted** `consumedMedicine` list. When I delete an item from the list I have given the position of the item in the **sorted** list, but I deleted the item at `position` from the **unsorted** list. This really seemed to fix it.

Comment: `but it gets weird when deleting items from that list.` code pls

Comment: Sry, added code part plus explanation.

Comment: I just had an idea what the problem may be: In my above delete-code I call `consumedMedicine.remove(itemToDelete)` without deleting it from the database. Does that update the adapter? I guess yes, but it´s just a guess that something may be wrong with this code snippet ...

Comment: Is `RealmList<Medicine> consumedMedicine;`  the same to medicineListAdapter's list ?

Comment: How do you obtain `position`?

Comment: @Rust Fisher `medicineListAdapter.updateData(consumedMedicine.sort("timeStamp"));`I bind the above `RealmResult` to the adapter.

Comment: Ahh. May it be that the problem is following: The adapter represents the **sorted** `consumedMedicine` list. BUT when I delete an item from the list I have given the position of the item in the **sorted** list, but I delete the item at position from the **unsorted** list. Could that be the problem? I will try as soon as possible.

Comment: `I have given the position of the item in the sorted list, but I delete the item at position from the unsorted list. Could that be the problem?` that is definitely the source of the problem

Comment: It really seemed to be the problem, quite happy now - thanks :) One question though, is it better to execute `RealmResult<Medicine> sortedList = consumedMedicine.sort("timeStamp");` once and store this as a member (is that even possible?) or call `consumedMedicine.sort(timeStamp).get(position)` every time I need the sorted list? Thanks.

Comment: I think the second option is easier on you.